# Why is Run With Powershell not executing my scripts correctly?

Tags: powershell

Copy-pasting the script into a powershell window where the beginning says "PS C:\Users\MyUsername" and then running it works perfectly and the script does what it's supposed to

But when I right-click on it and choose Run With Powershell, it doesn't work.

Why is this and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Things to note: If I run it as admin, it doesn't work. If I run it as standard user from my home directory (open powershell window -> it says PS C:\Users\MyUsername), it works perfectly. So apparently when I right-click on it and choose Run With Powershell, it doesn't run from inside the user's home directory.

Anyway how can I fix this guys? Thanks

Comment: Invoking a `.ps1` file via right-clicking (via the context menu) makes _whatever directory the file resides in_ the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted <-- Will not allow any powershell scripts to run.  Only individual commands may be run.
```

Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned <-- Will allow signed powershell scripts to run.

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned <-- Allows unsigned local script and signed remote powershell scripts to run.

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted <-- Will allow unsigned powershell scripts to run.  Warns before running downloaded scripts.

Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass <-- Nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts.`

I think the ExecutionPolicy might be a reason, try running `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

or try checking the directory powershell is in when you are opening it as admin. if it is not the same as `C:Users\MyUsername` navigate to the directory and now it should work.
This may help you know how to trasverse between directories.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/232442/how-do-i-navigate-between-directories-in-terminal

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that _execution policies_ are the problem. Instead, it seems to  be about _working directories_.

Comment: try checking the directory powershell is in when you are opening it as admin. if it is not the same as C:Users\MyUsername navigate to the directory and now it should work. This may help you know how to trasverse between directories. https://askubuntu.com/questions/232442/how-do-i-navigate-between-directories-in-terminal